# Datagrid Unwanted Scroll and Value Exception

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, exception, datagrid

I get data from database with my function without problem. After loading data, datagrid gets scroll.(While I want to show 2 column of 6 columns on form) While click on scroll, I get error which is called as:

> {"Value of '321' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between
>   'minimum' and 'maximum'.\r\nParameter name: Value"}

My code is shown as belove;

```
if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
                metroGridGrup.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                metroGridGrup.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                metroGridGrup.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
                for (var index = 0; index < metroGridGrup.Columns.Count; index++) {
                    metroGridGrup.Columns[index].Visible = false;
                }

                metroGridGrup.PerformLayout();

                metroGridGrup.Columns[0].Visible = true;
                metroGridGrup.Columns[0].HeaderText = "code"
                metroGridGrup.Columns[1].Visible = true;
                metroGridGrup.Columns[1].HeaderText = "value";

                metroGridGrup.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

            }
            else {
                metroGridGrup.DataSource = null;
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "blabla", "blabla", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
```

[image: Error Potin]
[image: Scroll Thing]

Comment: There is no error on these lines. Error appears the form.showdialog() which brings user to (next form) this screen.

Comment: Done @mjwills, i hope that helps.

Comment: Please include all source code for the form (both the cs file and the designer.cs file).

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Also you do not want to have your variables named exactly as their type `dataSet` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your advise but that doesn't solve my problem. It is edited code for private purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue, you should not assign your grid to null as shown below. Avoid using null assignment.

```
metroGridGrup.DataSource = null;
```